# Add icon to child context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, icons, contextmenu

I want to add an icon to my child context menus. But right now, the chrome extension [options for context menu](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create) doesnt provide any option to add icon while creating a child menu.
I can add icon to the parent menu [using the icon parameter in manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#manifest). But no option for the child menu.
Any idea how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, it is currently not possible. All you got is that one parent icon set through manifest.

Comment: Are Possible now in 2017 ?

Comment: Is it still not possible in 2023? (What is the matter with Google?)

Answer (score 11):

A possible workaround is using [Unicode Symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/#26D4):

<kbd>[image: example of context menu with icons]</kbd>

Adapted code from [this Google sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:context):

```js
// Create a parent item and two children.
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "⛔ Parent", "id": "parent"});
chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "♣ Child 1", "parentId": "parent", "id": "child1"});
chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "⚑ Child 2", "parentId": "parent", "id": "child2"});
```

*The submenu "Radio 1" behaves as a radio button, and it's defined with `chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Radio 1", "type": "radio", "id": "radio1"});`*

This is just one of many pages of symbols:

<kbd>[image: screenshot from unicode-table.com]</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

serg answer is no longer true. Add this snippet into your manifest:

```
"icons": {
   "16": "icon16.png", --> this icons will be used for you menu item
   "32": "icon32.png"
}
```

Comment: this is only correct form main context menu, not for child. But was what I was looking for, So thanks!