# Icons on contextMenu submenus in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got a working Chrome extension that adds an item to the context menu when right-clicking on an editable field.  I'm able to add an icon to my new top-level menu item, but I can't find a way to add icons to each of my submenu items.

You can see a screenshot of the menu here: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/5mRSIYNceNWZyUhUUZLdvMQC2ns9LDFMWwZFEmsx37Hop4YCe9dzmS2zQCdSoUOcAmaZqvup=s640-h400-e365

As you can see, to top-level item "GTZCode" has an icon, but all the items in that menu do not  have icons.  Is it possible to add icons to them?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772074/add-icon-to-context-menu . Relevant issue: http://crbug.com/53820 . Seems like this haven't changed for the last two years.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I didn't search well enough before asking. :)