# Add icons to Tampermonkey right click context menu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I have a basic script running in Tampermonkey on Chrome because I buy Steam codes online a lot, and this speeds up the process. It adds a right-click option on webpages to help redeem the key.

[image: Right-click menu]

Is there any way for me to add an icon to the "Redeem Steam Key" option? There's blank space on the left that's dying to have a little Steam icon in it.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Redeem Steam Key
// @namespace       http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description     Activate Steam key with right-click menu
// @version         0.2
// @author          Adam K
// @include         *
// @grant           GM_openInTab
// @run-at          context-menu
// @icon            https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/images/responsive/share_steam_logo.png
// ==/UserScript==]


(function() {
    'use strict';
    var sel = document.getSelection ();
    GM_openInTab("https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=" + sel);
})();
```

I tried using variations of `@icon` but that only adds an icon in the Tampermonkey UI:

[image: Tampermonkey UI]

I'd just like to know if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Tampermonkey (an extension) cannot do this, so it can't make the feature available to TM scripts on Chrome.  But it *might* (eventually) be possible for TM on Firefox or Vivaldi (**maybe**).

Comment: I added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646319/1287812) to the duplicate. We have some choices using [Unicode Symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/#26D4).